# Mysql weekday that doesn't return correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do a filter for a specific day of the week.

my php code include something like

```
Select * from table_name where Weekday(DATE(project_surveydate)) = 0;
```

If I use the above line in phpMyAdmin, it return the correct records for all records that are on Monday.

However, when I run that code through my php script, it return some records on Sunday.

The project_surveydate data type is timestamp.

I noticed that it only return the sunday that is at 21:00:00 or more.

for example if the project_surveydate is (Sunday) 2012-05-03 13:25:14, it will not be included it. IF it is 2012-05-03 21:25:14, it will be included in the results.

I really don't know what causing this. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is your timezone?

Comment: Are these examples legit? 2012-05-03 is a Thursday.

Comment: My timezone is EST. It seems like the search is base on the user current timezone. So i need to adjust the server time zone accordingly base on the user timezone

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your server timezone is affecting the results. You can set the timezone on a per-connection basis:

```
SET time_zone = '+00:00';
```

MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. You can change the default timezone for mysql in several ways, documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: timezones aren't stored in a MySQL datetime field. re: your edit: so then if it gets converted from the currently set timezone and back again why aren't they the same?

Comment: No, but the server timezone is used when retrieving timestamps.

Comment: My hunch is also that the timezones are doing some funny business, but that should affect _both_ phpMyAdmin and the script

Comment: We have our initialize.php which set the time-zone to '+00:00'.

Comment: I tried to add mysql_query("set time_zone = '-05:00'"); and mysql_query("set time_zone = '+00:00'"); at the beginning and the end of the sql and it works. I just need to figure out how to adjust the time according to user time zone

Comment: How are you viewing the actual dates that these timestamps convert to? If you are doing that from, say, PHPMyAdmin on one timezone while running your query from php in timezone '+00:00' that could be causing your problem.

Comment: Is your php on the same server as the database ?